# If someone doesn't know about Christianity, and they sin, do they go to hell?

Tags: philosophy

I was debating with a friend recently and he is from India, he never knew about Christianity until he came to the US, and he made a sin, will he go to hell?

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: you appear to be looking for the "true answer," but given the variety of views held by people who associate themselves with Christianity, we can't do that here.  Instead, we describe what specific groups of Christians believe, so if you'd like to ask for the view of a particular tradition, or an overview of positions, this question may be answerable.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](https://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: FWIW, this person won't go to hell while still living, and where there's life there's hope.  Your question is incomplete, beyond the point made about asking "truth" questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of different positions on this matter, [this link](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/what-about-those-who-havent-heard) is a very good summary.

To summarise even further the points in the article:

**1. Church Exclusivism** - outside *the church* there is no salvation (therefore there is no salvation for unreached people)

**2. Gospel Exclusivism** - outside *the gospel* there is no salvation (therefore there is no salvation for unreached people)

**3. Special Revelation Exclusivism** - outside *special revelation* there is no salvation (special revelation includes the gospel/the church, but also includes dreams/visions/direct words of God to non-believers and unreached people)

**4. Agnosticism** - neutral position, committed only to not knowing

**5.  General Revelation Inclusivism** - anyone can be saved by general revelation (belief in a non-religion specific God) but other religions are in no way instrumental to salvation

**6.  World Religions Inclusivism** - similar to (5), but also holds that other religions can be used for salvation.

**7.  Postmortem Evangelism** - unbelievers who die will have a chance to trust Christ after death

**8.  Universalism** - everyone will be ultimately saved by the Christian God

**9.  Pluralism** - everyone will be ultimately saved by God, the Christian image of which is no more or less valid than that of other religions

There's also a tenth position I'm aware of, but I can't find anybody willing to give it a name:

**10. Universalism for the unreached** - all unreached people will be saved, God only rejects those who reject him first

This is a very problematic position though, because it begs the question, why evangelise in the first place, given that it only decreases one's chance of salvation.